# Forward port to OpenVPN Client

Tags: iptables, openvpn, port-forwarding, nat

I have an `OpenVPN` Server running on my VPS. The clients behind that server are now able to surf on the internet as ***anonymous***. Now I want to forward a port to a client.

I already added these rules, without any success:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 28006 -j DNAT --to x.x.27.6
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 28006 -j DNAT --to x.x.27.6
```

After it was not working, I tried additional SNAT rules like here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55845/223140

I don't know what I should do now..

[image: iptables]

Comment: Please don't paste a screenshot; include the text instead. It's easier to read and it can be indexed and/or searched.

Comment: Got solved the problem: https://superuser.com/a/1193433/623661