# Remote Port forwarding using openvpn

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

So I am trying to setup remote port forwarding as is shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397627/port-forwarding-using-vpn-client) and using the accepted solution to just use the `openvpn` access server admin panel and create a dmz. I am trying to host a `rust` server behind this so I need 2 ports open, 28015 udp and 28016 tcp.

My config for the rustserver user is as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1PZs.png) but when I attempt to connect to the vpn server address on port 28015 in `rust` it refuses to connect. I am not sure if the client is getting the request or not; the server shell looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWpEl.png) while running the `openvpn` connection.

I am amicable to doing a bunch of `iptables` voodoo if I have to instead of just trying to use the control panel, but it appears that it could potentially be as easy as just settings in the control panel? It would also be nice to just background the `openvpn` connection and snoop on traffic to see if it even hits the client but not exactly sure what would be the proper utility to do so.

The openvpn server is running the application snapshot provided by default by Vultr, and the rust game server is running on a server inside of my own home. The vultr server runs ubuntu 18.04 and I run ubuntu 16.04 at home. Ideally I need anyone to be able to hit my server at port 28015 and the udp packets get transferred to my client and then routed back through the openvpn server to whoever originally sent the request.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a general note, attaching (or linking to) screenshots of console output is strongly [discouraged](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) as these are often difficult to read and will not show up for others googling for a similar issue. If possible, please copy-and-paste the log output into your question with appropriate formatting instead.

Comment: agreed, I think you need to restructure your question and add all the information required.... it looks a lot like all you need is ip_forwarding enabled and iptables rules to do the port forwarding. but it's difficult to understand where the rust server is, where the openvpn server is, who is the client and what kind of access you need.

Comment: It should be clearer now, I think the openvpn access server should have set the server side ip tables and ip forwarding rules but is there any command to check from ssh? I also don't know what ip table post routing rules the client/rust-server needs.